# How to access JSON values that are loaded inside of a html file?

Tags: javascript, json, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to take the coordinates from my JSON file and give them to Mapbox inside of an HTML file without manually typing in the data. I looked over some posts and found one that loads the json into my HTML file.

```
function loadJSON(callback) {   
  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  xobj.open('GET', 'C:\Users\ArkPr\yelp\restaurants.json', true);
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
      callback(JSON.parse(xobj.responseText));
    }
  };
  xobj.send(null);  
}
loadJSON(function(json) {
  var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(json);
```

This is great but I don't know how to access the values within the JSON file that I want, being the coordinates.

```
{
  "type": "featurecollections",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.153788,
          51.513878
        ]
      }
    },
   {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.162122,
          51.485349
        ]
      }
    },
// etc...
```

And make them work with the next few lines of code to place markers on a map.

```
for (const { geometry, properties } of actual_JSON.features) {
  // create a HTML element for each feature
  const el = document.createElement('div');
  el.className = 'marker';

  // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
  new mapboxgl.Marker(el).setLngLat(geometry.coordinates).addTo(map);
}
```

What am I missing that will make this all work as intended?

Comment: Can you maybe create a codepen or something?

Comment: I'm not sure where to put the JSON data so for the sake of including it, I'll leave it in the JS section. [Here](https://codepen.io/Measmyself/pen/LYLWvNX) it is.

Comment: I advise you to remove your access token and other personal info from the CodePen.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether to remove it or keep it there so cheers for that.

Comment: You could just fake the json response.

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an online mock JSON server like https://www.npoint.io/ and the code will be like;

```
$.getJSON("https://api.npoint.io/43c8857fb1f218a3b356", null, (actual_JSON)=>{
  actual_JSON.features.forEach((feature)=> {
    const el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el).setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates).addTo(map);
  });
});
```

Comment: This seems like it could be just what I need but I have to ask, how is the `"https://api.npoint.io/43c8857fb1f218a3b356"` generated?

Comment: You can create a JSON Bin from https://www.npoint.io/ There may be other similar services as well...

Comment: In other words, I'm uploading the JSON data and then retrieving afterwards or something like that right? Doesn't work for me unless it would be possible to automatically upload the data and then retrieve it without having to manually input the data somewhere.

Comment: This is just a way to mock your `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: In this case you should have your own server to serve your JSON. But since you are somehow going to serve your HTML, you can use the same place to serve that JSON. I believe you can automatically upload the JSON to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop should be something like this:

```js
var json = {
  "type": "featurecollections",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.153788,
          51.513878
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.162122,
          51.485349
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.101429,
          51.513136
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.138386,
          51.512087
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -100.445882,
          39.78373
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.192881,
          51.504062
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.089901,
          51.505143
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -100.445882,
          39.78373
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.139175,
          51.492591
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -100.445882,
          39.78373
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

for (let feature of json.features) {    
  const el = document.createElement('div');
  el.className = 'marker';
  
  console.log(feature.geometry.coordinates);
}
```

You also need to move everything related with `map` inside the `loadJson()` method and joining both you'll end up with something like this:

```
function loadJSON(callback) {
  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  xobj.open("GET", "C:\Users\ArkPr\yelp\restaurants.json", true);
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
      callback(JSON.parse(xobj.responseText));
    }
  };
  xobj.send(null);
}

loadJSON(function(json) {
  mapboxgl.accessToken = ':3';

  const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: "map",
    style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
    center: [-0.19346, 51.50405],
    zoom: 9
  });

  for (let feature of json.features) {
    const el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';

    // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el).setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates).addTo(map);
  }
});
```

Comment: That works true, but then I'm manually entering the JSON data into the HTML file which doesn't work for me.

Comment: This is just an example. You just have to replace it with `var json = loadJson(...)` or similar.

Comment: I don't understand how am I accessing the coordinates in this case?

Comment: Not sure if understood your question but you access the coordinates of each feature with `feature.geometry.coordinates` inside the for loop.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense and when I change the console.log statement to a `new mapboxgl.Marker` one and manually input the json data it works. Could you explain what you meant before with `var json = loadJson(...)` bit? Sorry if I'm being a little annoying at this point.

Comment: See my edit to the answer. The code I added is not tested but should work if your `XMLHttpRequest` part is working and in fact getting the local json.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236967/discussion-between-measmyself-and-iamdlm).

Comment: In that case, my XML file must not be working properly though I'm not sure why it wouldn't load the json.